# NHibernate 1.2 Upgrade assistance

Tags: nhibernate, upgrade

I need to upgrade from NHibernate 1.2.x to the latest version. Can someone help me out by either pointing me into the right direction, explain to me what I need to do, or just shoot me for using 1.2 when it's almost 2013.

Please.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Answer: Have you tried just dropping in the latest version?  3.x should be somewhat compatible with what you have.

Hard Answer: Download Fluent NHibernate and get ready for some fun learning.  It all depends on why you feel the need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The release notes in the download list know and possible breaking changes. It may be worth looking through. Other than that, I would suggest just dropping the new files in and see what happens.